# chaining ssh tcp port forwarding

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I need to connect to a DB server which accepts connections on port 1521, I can only access this from a remote machine which I need to ssh in to through *another* gateway.

ie from home

home $ ssh user@gateway

gateway $ ssh desktop

desktop $ < I now have access to port 1521 on host dbserver >

What are the commands I need to use for this, so that I would then connect to localhost:1521 on home pc for db connections

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of chaining:

---

1. Connect from *home* to *gateway*, forwarding `localhost:1521` on *home* via *gateway* to `localhost:PORT`.
2. Connect from *gateway* to *desktop*, forwarding `localhost:PORT` on *gateway* via *desktop* to `dbserver:1521`.

```
home$ ssh -ftL 1521:localhost:PORT gateway ssh -NL PORT:dbserver:1521 desktop
```

*PORT* can be 1521 or any other port.

---

1. Connect from *home* to *gateway*, forwarding `localhost:PORT` on *home* via *gateway* to `desktop:22`.
2. Connect from *home* to *desktop* using the established tunnel via *gateway*, forwarding `localhost:1521` on *home* via *desktop* to `dbserver:1521`.

```
home$ ssh -fNL PORT:desktop:22 gateway
home$ ssh -fNL 1521:dbserver:1521 -o "HostkeyAlias=desktop" -P PORT localhost
DB connection can be made now
```

(The `-fN` options tell SSH to connect, establish tunnels, then continue running in background.)

---

The second method is more useful, since it allows you to reach *desktop* directly from *home* (using the running tunnel) for all kinds of connections.

Comment: Thanks for posting that answer, I now realise I'm actually up against an altogether bigger problem as the dbserver just listens on that port, it immediately opens another port for communication. Think this is trickier than I can handle...